# TextView looks different on Simulator and iPhone than what I design on Storyboard

Tags: xcode, textview, interface-builder, xcode6

I have this multiline TextView. I load data into it from Core Data.

I edited text to be Thin Helvetica Neue 36px in White, just like how you see below-right, but it looks so different in simulators. Any idea why?

I'm using Xcode 6 Beta 5

---

Left: Simulator

Right: Storyboard (what I want)

Bottom: Simulator on iPhone

---

Thanks!

[image] 
[image: Simulator(left) - Storyboard(right)]

Comment: Are you using beta 5 of Xcode 6?

Comment: Matt, yes it is Xcode 6 beta 5

Comment: Okay, just checking. I can't seem to reproduce the issue here.